# What's the fastest way to delete an array of my model objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-5, destroy

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to delete a bunch of records from a table.  I have

```
currencies = CryptoCurrency.order('latest_market_cap_in_usd desc').limit(num_currencies)
current_index_currencies = CryptoIndexCurrency.all.pluck(:crypto_currency_id)

currencies_to_remove = current_index_currencies - currencies
...
currencies_to_remove.each do |currency|
  currency.destroy
end
```

where "currencies_to_remove" is supposed to contain an array of all the models that I want to delete.  But I get the below error when iterating over the list

```
2.4.0 :005 > svc.create_index
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "crypto_index_currencies"."crypto_currency_id" FROM "crypto_index_currencies"
  CryptoCurrency Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "crypto_currencies".* FROM "crypto_currencies" ORDER BY latest_market_cap_in_usd desc LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 12]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for 1020:Integer
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever/numeric.rb:10:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/services/crypto_index_service.rb:17:in `block in create_index'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/services/crypto_index_service.rb:16:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cindex/app/services/crypto_index_service.rb:16:in `create_index'
    from (irb):5
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `currencies_to_remove` contains the indexes of the models to remove, rather than the models. Thus, `destroy` method is undefined.

The fastest way to delete them is going to be `delete` method on the model class:

```
CryptoCurrency.delete(currencies_to_remove)
```

But if you need to call the callbacks on destroy, you might need the `destroy` method:

```
CryptoCurrency.destroy(currencies_to_remove)
```

Note, that the `destroy` method will raise the `RecordNotFound` exception, if any record in specified array is not found